# How can I stop a loop when an error occurs in imacros?

Tags: imacros

I want to fill my from four times.i take one csv file with four columns data.after inserting the first data one error is occurred.but imacros loop is not stoped.it leaves the first error and continuing other process.i want to stop the loop when error occured.

Answer (score 1):

remove `set !errorignore` from your script